# springframework: Error starting ApplicationContext after enabling SSL

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat, https

I tried to enable SSL with Spring Boot and I am facing error on starting ApplicationContext. The application is starting without the ssl configuration. Furthermore I have class CustomSecurityConfiguration extending the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter where the HttpSecurity with all filters is configured.

java.version: 11.0.8

ERROR

```
ERROR 8360 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
```

Application.properties

```
server.ssl.key-store=certificate.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias=testalias
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

pom.xml dependancies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Console

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.4)

2021-08-18 14:06:34.969  INFO 8360 --- [           main] com.TestApplication     : Starting TestApplication using Java 11.0.8 on DESKTOP-H3DO6R2 with PID 8360
2021-08-18 14:06:34.972  INFO 8360 --- [           main] com.TestApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-08-18 14:06:35.814  INFO 8360 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-08-18 14:06:35.941  INFO 8360 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 115 ms. Found 11 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-08-18 14:06:36.928  INFO 8360 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9092 (https)
2021-08-18 14:06:36.942  INFO 8360 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-08-18 14:06:36.943  INFO 8360 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.44]
2021-08-18 14:06:37.118  INFO 8360 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-08-18 14:06:37.118  INFO 8360 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2071 ms
2021-08-18 14:06:37.472  INFO 8360 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-08-18 14:06:37.701  INFO 8360 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-08-18 14:06:37.757  INFO 8360 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-08-18 14:06:37.803  INFO 8360 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
2021-08-18 14:06:37.935  INFO 8360 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-08-18 14:06:38.115  INFO 8360 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
2021-08-18 14:06:38.986  INFO 8360 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-08-18 14:06:38.996  INFO 8360 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-08-18 14:06:39.651  WARN 8360 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-08-18 14:06:40.266  INFO 8360 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5c40402c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@24fb752f, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2dfab167, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2e4d252, com.security.CustomJwtAuthenticationFilter@7dbd70fd, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@145ef9e8, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@628f0936, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@198524ec, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7940b729, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@59cb10e0, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3146f3d7]
2021-08-18 14:06:40.428  INFO 8360 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-08-18 14:06:40.822  INFO 8360 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2021-08-18 14:06:41.153  WARN 8360 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
2021-08-18 14:06:41.154  INFO 8360 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2021-08-18 14:06:41.155  INFO 8360 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-08-18 14:06:41.162  INFO 8360 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-08-18 14:06:41.164  INFO 8360 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-08-18 14:06:41.177  INFO 8360 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-08-18 14:06:41.178  INFO 8360 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-08-18 14:06:41.192  INFO 8360 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-08-18 14:06:41.213 ERROR 8360 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at com.TestApplication.main(TestApplication.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:244) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1075) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alias name [testalias] does not identify a key entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:258) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1204) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1290) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:614) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1072) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Alias name [testalias] does not identify a key entry
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:336) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:246) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Alias name [testalias] does not identify a key entry`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the certificate. I created it new and now is working:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in <domain-name.crt> -inkey </path-to private.key> -name <alias-name> -out <domain-name.p12>
```

Thank you for the support!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to generate the key with that alias first and then start the service:

`keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias testalias -keystore certificate.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -keysize 2048 -validity 3650`